# Draw a circle that doesn't "break" when resized in Java

Tags: java, swing, awt, geometry, graphics2d

How can I draw a circle that is resizable when the window is maximized or minimized? The code I have isn't really even draw the circle like I would like it to either. Any help with this would be greatly appreciated as I have never worked with graphics in Java before and the Oracle site is only helping me so much.  Thanks.

```
public class GUI extends JFrame {


    public GUI() {
        JPanel p1 = new JPanel();


    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
        g2d.drawOval(0, 0, 50, 50);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        GUI frame = new GUI();
        frame.setTitle("Circle Generator");
        frame.setSize(400, 300);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null); // Center the frame
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
```

Comment: So draw the oval according to the the (graphic/frame) size, not always "50x50".

Answer (score 2):

To make the painting dynamic you need to get the current width/height of the panel.

```
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) 
{
    super.paintComponent(g);
    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
    //g2d.drawOval(0, 0, 50, 50);
    g2d.drawOval(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
}
```

You also need the super.paintComponent(g) to clear the background of the panel.

Edit:

Actually, I took a closer look at your code and it does nothing. A JFrame does not have a paintComponent() method so your code will never be executed. Also, you create a panel but then don't do anything with it.

Start by reading the section from the Swing tutorial on [Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html) for more information and working examples.

Then you can modify the example from the tutorial to draw your oval, using the suggestion give above.

Comment: Well after reading that tutorial I'm even more confused on how to apply those ideas to my code.

Comment: @Ben, Exactly, because your code is not well structured. That is why I suggested you start with the tutorial example code. Then you just replace the `drawstring(...)` statement with the `drawOval(...)` statement. Don't try to change your code. Start with a working example to learn a better structure!